# Android: Emojis from MySQL to TextView

Tags: android, ios, emoji

I have a database with `Utf8_mb4_general_ci` with my emojis. (**\ud83d\ude3b**)
iOS works. But if i will display this unicode in a `TextView(Android)`. It is not working. Can you help me?

This is my JSON:

```
[{"user_bewerten":"","anz_com":"7","rating":"0","id":"291","titel":"\\ud83d\\ude3b","text":"\\ud83d\\ude3b","cityId":"2","city_name":"Aachen","userId":"1359280c82c7c0804c5ad3235153346dc2bdde45c7150cda88ae59f2e206d61b","created_at":"2016-06-20 10:58:02"}]
```

This is my function:

```
Context context = this.curContext.getApplicationContext();
        CheckInternetConnectionChangeReceiver cm = new CheckInternetConnectionChangeReceiver();
        if(cm.CheckInternetConnection(context))
        {
            boolean bErg = connectSchnacken(url);

            if(bErg==true)
            {
                Log.d("2","2");
                try {
                    Log.d("2","2");
                    dataJSON = json;
                    Log.d("dataJSON: ",dataJSON.toString());
                    if(dataJSON.length() > 0){
                        bLeer = false;
                        for(int i = 0; i < dataJSON.length(); i++){
                            Log.d("id: "+i, ""+i);
                            JSONObject c = dataJSON.getJSONObject(i);

                            classSchnacken thisContent = new classSchnacken();
                                thisContent.setId(c.getInt("id"));
                                String id = ""+c.getInt("id");
                                Log.d("id: "+i, ""+c.getInt("id"));
                                thisContent.setTitle(c.getString("titel"));
                                Log.d("Titel: "+i, c.getString("titel"));
                                thisContent.setText(c.getString("text"));
                                Log.d("Text: "+i, c.getString("text"));
                                thisContent.setUser(c.getString("userId"));
                                Log.d("userId: "+i, c.getString("userId"));
                                thisContent.setTime(c.getString("created_at"));
                                Log.d("Time: "+i, c.getString("created_at"));
                                thisContent.setCityName(c.getString("city_name"));
                                thisContent.setAnzKommentare(c.getString("anz_com"));
                                thisContent.setAnzBewertungen(c.getString("rating"));

                                String currentMail = getEmailAccount();
                                if(c.getString("user_bewerten").toLowerCase().contains(currentMail.toLowerCase())==true)
                                {
                                    thisContent.setBewertungsStatus("1");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    thisContent.setBewertungsStatus("0");
                                }
                                Log.d("user_bewerten: "+i, c.getString("user_bewerten"));
                                Log.d("user_bewerten: "+i, thisContent.getBewertungsStatus());
                            // ADD
                            dataListTemp.add(thisContent);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bLeer = true;
                        Log.d("leer", "leer");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Fehler: ", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dataListSchnacken = (ArrayList<classSchnacken>) dataListTemp;

    return dataListTemp;
  }
```

PHP:

```
  $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
  if (mysql_errno())
  {
     header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
     echo $query.'\n';
     echo mysql_error();
  }
  else
  {
     if( $query_exec!=null)
     {
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
            print(json_encode($output));
     }
     else {echo "No Data"; }
     mysql_close(); 
   }
```

$query_search is my SQL-Query.

Comment: You could take a look at [unescapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.lang.String))

Comment: What does *It is not working* mean? Doesn't it compile? Does the app crash? Does it display gibberish? Does it brew coffee instead?

Comment: Your sample JSON data has a double backslash? That's not what you want. Is this how the data is transferred or is this an artifact from a tool such a copying it from the debugger?

Comment: Thank you, i look into it. It means: The TextViews doesnt display the emojis. The Titletag (JSON) is Content of a TextView. It shows "\ud83d\ude3b". This is how the data transferred. How can I change it?

Comment: unescapeJava()  WORKS, THANK YOU.